# C Socket Programming with Polling: How to detect if client hangs up

Tags: c, linux, gnu

I am working on a simple C program where there are two source files: server.c and client.c

I connected everything properly with sockets, and I use the poll() function to poll the keyboard for data (as well as a shell connected to a pipe).

I am able to detect when the client uses the ^D and ^C command to know to kill the child process, and exit both client and server terminals.

However, is there a way to detect if the client hangs up (i.e. I explicitly click x on the client terminal tab)? Because right now, the server tab doesn't detect this, and doesn't close. I want to avoid using a timeout

Comment: If you are using plain TCP, it is not possible to detect unsignaled client/server death. If the peer just dies, or otherwise becomes unreachable, without a TCP close exchange or attempted data exchanges like using KEEPALIVE or application-level poliing, the other end will never know.

Answer (score 1):

You can continuously probe the client socket with the `recv()` sys call. It is designed to return 0 when the client disconnects.

```
while (1) {

  //Get request from client, leave if client quits
  if (recv(client_socket, client_request, sizeof(client_request), 0) == 0) {
    break;
  }
}
```

OR

```
// This while condition will fail when recv returns 0, because C
while (recv(client_socket, client_request, sizeof(client_request), 0)) {
 // insert code here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ' It is designed to return 0 when the client no longer sends anything' - no.